# Start the First screen each time app comes from background in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin, launchmode

I have an app that has 5 activities (A,B,C,D,E). The app can navigate between those activities. When the user presses home button in device the app goes background and after when the app comes to foreground, first activity should be launched i.e A activity.

Example: app in D activity, after pressing home, the app goes background and when it comes to foreground again it should open A activity not D.

Solutions which i have tried is launch mode, I set the launch mode for A activity (singleInstance) but could not able to find the required solution.

Comment: Since the question has no information about back button, maybe the [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag is the thing you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For launch same Activty you Should clear all the Activity when app goes into background.When app goes background use below code that will clear current activity and all other activity that are in stack.

For API 16+, use

finishAffinity();

For lower (Android 4.1 lower), use

ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(YourActivity.this);

Comment: Thank you for your reply , this is the only solution which is worked for me

Answer (score 3):

When you press Home-Button change to Activity A. Maybe this will work:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivityName.class); 
        //replace MyActivityName.class with the name of your Activity A
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you may get ondestroy() or onpause() method. on it youcan do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); //
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" for Activity A in your manifest file to achieve what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beispieldomain.stackoverflowxmlparse">

    <application
        ...
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Have a look here:

[Managing Tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks)
[clearTaskOnLaunch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)